# How can I disable the Emacs NEWS shortcut?

Tags: key-bindings

While coding, I'll occasionally fat-finger a key combo and find myself dropped into the GNU Emacs NEWS buffer (`M-x view-emacs-news` or `C-h n`). This is never what I want, since it totally breaks my flow.

How can I globally remove the `C-h n` binding for `M-x view-emacs-news` across all modes, without removing any other bindings that other modes might define for `C-h n`? A solution that would remove `M-x view-emacs-news` entirely is also fine since I don't use the feature.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h n") nil)
```

or

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-h n"))
```

Or interactively: `M-x global-unset-key` `C-h n`